# Servlet de Imagens para Projeto JSF "Travando" o Servidor de Aplicação

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2.2, servlet, glassfish

Tenho o seguinte código que fornece ao meu portal as imagens que estão no banco de dados

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String id = req.getParameter("id");


    if(id.equals("logo")){
        resp.setContentType(museu.getConfiguracao().getContentTypeLogo());
        resp.getOutputStream().write(museu.getConfiguracao().getLogo());

    }else if(req.getParameter("slide")!=null){
        resp.setContentType(banco.getSlide(id).getContentType());
        resp.getOutputStream().write(banco.getSlide(id).getContent());

    }
    else{
        Foto foto = museu.getFoto(Long.parseLong(id));
        resp.setContentType(foto.getContentType());
        resp.getOutputStream().write(foto.getContent());
    }
}
```

O problema, quando tento fazer a requisição de 3/4 ou mais imagens para uma mesma página, o servidor de aplicação(Glassfish) simplesmente "pendura" e depois de um tempo solta o erro, as imagens geralmente são carregadas um pouco(umas 10%, outras 50%) mas simplesmente o server "trava" do nada. Headers dos Erros no log:

```
2014-03-21T08:58:20.561-0300|Grave: java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.Exceptions.makeIOException(Exceptions.java:81)

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.blockAfterWriteIfNeeded(OutputBuffer.java:951)
... 36 more

2014-03-21T08:58:20.567-0300|Advertência: StandardWrapperValve[MultiMidiaServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet MultiMidiaServlet threw exception
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.blockAfterWriteIfNeeded(OutputBuffer.java:951)
... 36 more
```

Comment: essas requisições que você está fazendo, são para a mesma imagem? Já considerou usar um cache, para não ler o stream da imagem em toda requisição?

Comment: São para imagens diferentes, até para 3 imagens funciona normalmente, fazer um cache como?

Comment: Então consegui "resolver" o problema, parecia ser um bug no grizzly , um modulo do glassfish que gerencia o conteiner de servlet, peguei um release do servidor no repositorio que tem uma versão mais autualizada do grizzly e não ocorre mais o problema :)

Answer (score 1):

Já tive que fazer isso uma vez. O que **eu estou achando bastante estranho é o Glassfish "travar"** em algumas fotos e funcionar em outras. É isso mesmo? Enfim, segue o código que eu usei para fazer quase a mesma coisa que você. Só que no meu *servlet* há integração com o *Spring* que você pode ignorar.

Enfim, não é complicado de se entender. Tente adaptar a sua necessidade e veja se funciona.

O funcionamento desse *servlet* é basicamente é buscar uma foto no banco de dados (oracle) onde a coluna da foto é um ***blob***. Estou usando **JPA**, então a entidade para a foto é `ColaboradorFoto`.

A chamada desse servlet ficaria assim: `http://www.example.com/foto?matricula=123456` por exemplo. A foto apareceria no navegador.

```
@Component("fotoServlet")
@WebServlet("/foto")
public class FotoServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7451359765915659089L;
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(FotoServlet.class);

    public FotoServlet() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String matricula = request.getParameter("matricula");

        if (matricula != null && !matricula.isEmpty()) {
            OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
            response.setContentType("image/jpg");

            WebApplicationContext springContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
            ColaboradorService colaboradorService = springContext.getBean(ColaboradorService.class);

            try {
                ColaboradorFoto colabFoto = colaboradorService.getColaboradorFoto(Long.parseLong(matricula));
                if (colabFoto != null && colabFoto.getFoto() != null) {
                    byte[] imgData = colabFoto.getFoto();
                    o.write(imgData);
                }
                else {
                    o.write(this.getFotoDefault());
                }

            }
            catch (ServiceException e) {
                o.write(this.getFotoDefault());
                logger.error("Erro ao obter a foto do colaborador no banco de dados", e);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                o.write(this.getFotoDefault());
                logger.warn("Matricula passada nao contem somente numeros. Retornando foto default", e);
            }

            o.flush();
            o.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.doGet(request, response);
    }

    private byte[] getFotoDefault() {
        InputStream input = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/resources/images/sem_foto.png");

        try {
            return IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Erro ao tentar obter foto padrao para colaborador", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Refatorei todo o codigo e ainda assim estou tendo problemas, com os testes que fiz aqui o problema acontece no seguinte caso, quando coloco 3 imagens de +/- 400k funciona normal, quando coloco mais uma de 400k, começa o travamento, deve ser algo relacionado a memória do servidor , vou tentar configurar isso ou limitar o tamanho do upload                      ps: Curti a parte de imagem indisponivel, ja coloquei no codigo aqui \o

Comment: Muito estranho esse problema do Glassfish começar a travar. Já tentou em algum outro servidor ou outra versão do próprio Glassfish para ver se não está relacionado com o servidor?